# Колесо прокрутки динамически-созданного элемента

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть пользовательский элемент(UserControl), в нем должна быть прокрутка. Если этот элемент просто создать в форме, то прокрутка есть, а если создавать его динамическим способом, то ее не видно.

Что должно быть

[image: Пользовательский элемент]

Вот что есть

[image: при динамическом создании]

Вот код, который создает этот элемент

[image: код динамического создания]

Comment: WinForms, WPF или еще что-то?

Comment: @rdorn WinForms

Comment: В одном контейнере с UserControl другие контролы есть?

Comment: @rdorn не понял на счет контейнера(конструктор?). В этом контроле пока что только цветные панельки и больше ничего

Comment: что в самом контроле не важно. Он на чем расположен, прямо на форме или внутри панели какой-нибудь? Он там один или рядом еще что-то есть? Прокрутка должна включаться на самом контроле? Лучше вместо картинок опишите компоновку формы. Решений много, но не любое подойдет. В угадайку играть не хочу.

Comment: самый простой вариант - вставляете его в конструкторе, смотрите что сгенерировалось в .designer.cs, удаляете, а в вашем коде повторяете код из дизайнера. А потом внимательно читаете какое свойство за что отвечает.